# Show html class in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following php strings :

```
<?php if($wc_options['woocommerce_catalog'] == 'true'): ?>
    // My Custom BUTTON Goes Here                  
  <?php endif; ?>
```

I'd like to use woocommerce in catalogue mode, so this code displays Send Enquiry button instead of the standard Add to cart button.

I have a custom Send Enquiry button that has a class, in html it is :

```
<a href="#url" class="store-button">Send Enquiry</a>
```

I am struggling to show the button. I can always see the Send Enquiry text link, but the button/class just doesn't seem to be showing up.

I've been trying the following variations :

```
<?php if($wc_options['woocommerce_catalog'] == 'true'): ?>

// var-1  
echo "<a href='".#url."' class='store-button'>Send Enquiry</a>";
// var-2
<?php echo "<a href='#url' class='store-button'>Send Enquiry</a>"; ?>
// var-3                   
<a href="#url" class="store-button">Send Enquiry</a>; 

<?php endif; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is setting the value of `$wc_options['woocommerce_catalog']`? Check there.

Comment: That comes from my wordpress / woocommerce theme, an option to show Woocommerce as normal shop mode or the catalogue mode. My theme has a setting for that. In catalog mode, the Add to Cart button is taken off.

Comment: I even tried changing the class for an ID instead or using ID together with the class, or placing the whole thing inside `<div>` tags. I can see the text link, but still can't see the bloody button ..

Comment: Other than its part of other code, is there another reason to evaluate `$wc_options['woocommerce_catalog']` because based on your issue, the value is not "true" and therefore your block of code doesn't run.

Comment: If the block of code wasn't running, I wouldn't see the text link ( #url ) either, correct ?
The link shows up with no problems, just not the styling ..

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you are saying the button is showing as text instead of applying the `.store_button` rule from the css.  Is that correct?  If so, I think we need to see your CSS.  Is the rest of the CSS working properly?  Do you have rules AFTER .store_button that are working properly?

Comment: Correct, button is showing as text instead of applying the `.store-button` css rule. No rules after `.store-button` applied. I've got the same css class applied n other pages, and all seem to be working just fine. CSS class as follows :

Comment: `.store-button {
background-color: #da4c26;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
border: 0;
border-radius: 6px;    
} `

Comment: GOT IT, of course, stupid me .. I was working with a wrong style sheet !! Many thanks for your help guys trying to figure this out !

Answer (score 0):

```
// var-2
<?php echo "<a href='#url' class='store-button'>Send Enquiry</a>"; ?>

// var-3                   
<a href="#url" class="store-button">Send Enquiry</a>;
```

Both variations var-2 and var-3 are correct and work.

Var-1 is wrong as the echo is outside the php tags.

The error was elsewhere as per the comments, I was working with the wrong css style sheet, therefore the CSS class failed to show correctly.